# Retrieving specific key value pairs from URL using Axios API

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use axios to retrieve data from a url and then print our specific key value pairs from the JSON retrieved. This is what I have written

```
const newArr = ["javascript","bootstrap","technology","jquery","node"]
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/articles')
      .then((resp) => {
      newArr.forEach((item) => {
        console.log(`headline: ${resp.data.articles[item].headline} id: ${resp.data.articles[item].authorName}` );
    })
  })
```

In a nutshell the URL has the titles; Javascript, Bootstrap, Technology, jQuery and Node.

For each of this I want to print out the associated headline and authorName.

My code returns

```
headline: undefined id: undefined
headline: undefined id: undefined
headline: undefined id: undefined
headline: undefined id: undefined
headline: undefined id: undefined
```

I expect to retrieve the values

```
headline: 'ES8: The Next Step in the Evolution of Javascript and What it Means For Your Projects' id: 'SIR RUFF'N'STUFF'
headline: 'Type Coercion: Why Does NaN !== NaN? and Other Strange Occurrences' id: 'BONES R. LIFE'
headline: "When to Rest, When to Spread: Why There Are Two Meanings Behind '...'" id: 'PUPPER S. DOGGO'
headline: 'Typescript: Ten Things you Should Know Before Building Your Next Angular Application' id: "SIR RUFF'N'STUFF"
headline: 'Bootstrap 5: Get a Sneak Peak at all the New Features' id: 'FIDO WALKSALOT'
headline: 'UI Frameworks: A Comparison, Which Made Our List? (Hint: Bootstrap is on it)' id: 'MAX GOODBOYE'
headline: 'The Hottest New Bootstrap 4 Components Every Developer Needs to Know About' id: 'MAX GOODBOYE'
headline: 'AI: What Are the Ethical Ramifications of the Future?' id: 'MAX GOODBOYE'
...
```

**UPDATE**

This is what I get when I do a `console.log(resp.data)`

```
{
  articles: {
    javascript: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    bootstrap: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    technology: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    jquery: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    node: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
{
  articles: {
    javascript: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    bootstrap: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    technology: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    jquery: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    node: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
{
  articles: {
    javascript: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    bootstrap: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    technology: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    jquery: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    node: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
{
  articles: {
    javascript: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    bootstrap: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    technology: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    jquery: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    node: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
{
  articles: {
    javascript: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    bootstrap: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    technology: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    jquery: [ [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    node: [ [Object], [Object] ]
  }
}
```

Comment: can you `console.log()` resp.data and see what it spits out?

Comment: @JaivBhup I have added that to my question under update

Comment: It looks like you have an array of objects for each language. Try getting the first element for each language like this headline: `${resp.data.articles[item][0].headline} id: ${resp.data.articles[item][0].authorName}`

Comment: @JaivBhup I understand how to get the first item, I want my forEach statement to return each element

Answer (score 0):

You need a nested loop for this:

```
const newArr = ["javascript","bootstrap","technology","jquery","node"]
axios.get('http://localhost:5000/api/articles')
      .then((resp) => {
      newArr.forEach((item) => {
           resp.data.articles[item].forEach((obj)=>{
                console.log(`headline: ${obj.headline} id: ${obj.authorName}` );
           })
        
    })
  })
```